# When im NOT on VPN -- Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at

Tags: php, jquery, node.js, socket.io, cross-domain

If I am VPN'd to my company network the SSL external website (https://mysite.company.com) WORKS FINE with node/socket.io

Once I log off VPN and access the site, it gives that error below in browser console:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote 
resource at https://mysite.company.com:8080/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&
t=1415132537790-0. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.
```

I don't know why this only happens when I'm off VPN...there are no requests other than mysite.company.com ... I have tried so many different methods to resolve this from researching this well known error....nothing has worked, i'm really hoping I can get some support...please!

**I have this in my .htaccess file:**

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "1000"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "x-requested-with, Content-Type, origin, authorization, accept, client-security-token"

Options FollowSymLinks

# Added a rewrite to respond with a 200 SUCCESS on every OPTIONS request.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

**my client.php (html section) file:**

```
<script src="/js/socket.io-1.1.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var socket = io.connect('https://mysite.company.com:8080');

socket.on('notification', function(data) {
    alert(data.message);
});
</script>
```

**my nodeServer.js:**

```
var connectionsArray = [];
//var app = require('express')();
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    key:    fs.readFileSync('C:/certs/mysite_company_com.key'),
    cert:   fs.readFileSync('C:/certs/star_company_com.crt'),
    ca:     fs.readFileSync('C:/certs/DigiCertCA.crt'),
    requestCert: true,
    rejectUnauthorized: false
};

var server = https.createServer(options);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080, 'mysite.company.com');

io.set('origins', '*:*');
```

Comment: If you look at the network tab in Chrome, does the request sent to mysite.company.com:8080/socket.io/ respond with CORS headers? Also, is it using the different transports in different cases? For example, that URL contains `transport=polling`. Does it do a different one on VPN?

Comment: @loganfsmyth  its showing transport=websocket on VPN .. the cross-origin error is caused from the port 8080 i'm using for node/socketio...

Comment: Perhaps connecting off-VPN causes some proxying somewhere, and that proxy doesn't support websockets. That still doesn't explain why you get the CORS error, you'll just have to do some debugging. Is the response from the server missing it's CORS headers?

Comment: @loganfsmyth proxy could be causing this as well... the headers are there... i have to troubleshoot further

Comment: Could you add to your question what you find? Show what headers you are getting and such?